# impersonation step in sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: impersonation

I have created impersanotion step in SPD workflow in which created by has read access.
Now created by user can view only their own item. I want to set it so that user can see all items whether it is created by them or not. What modification I need to do in impersonation step?

Comment: That is not possible with your current workflow.  You would have to loop through each item in the list/library, and then add view only/read permissions to the item.  Since 2010 Designer Workflows do not have the ability to loop, you need to get creative.  This [link](http://sharepointgypsy.blogspot.com/2011/11/create-for-each-loop-for-workflows.html) shows how to do so.  You will need two additional workflows and lists to accomplish it.  I have not actually tried this, so I cannot provide a detailed answer.

Comment: Can't I use action replace list item permission in impersonation step and add NT authority as read access.
In my case it is not working, but do not know why

Comment: Well, you cannot simply add list item permission to every item in the list.  That's where you'd need to iterate through each list item.  As for why NT Authority is not being added, I'd need to see what exactly you are doing to determine what could be going wrong.